# Add view to ViewGroup only if there is enough space left

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view, android-listview, android-viewgroup

I have scrollable horizontal RecyclerView filled with same size items.

I need to change behaviour of that ViewGroup and have 4 requirements:

- not scrollable
- as many items as space left (all items needs to be displayed with full size)
- if there is more items to display than space left - show "ellipsize" item at the end
- items takes equal space (similar to `layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle=”spread”`)

I tried to play with [Flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) but I am not sure if this is a correct tool to achieve it. Also before I started trying to implement it by myself (measure; add item if space left > item.size), I wanted to ask if there is already easy solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created `EllipsizeViewGroup` for that. Layout is based on `LinearLayout`. You can add more views dynamically.

https://github.com/Bresiu/EllipsizeViewGroup/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bresiu/ellipsizeviewgroup/EllipsizeViewGroup.kt